# why is the dot product of rotated basis vectors not zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, python

I wrote a python script that creates a rotation matrix

```
from math import *
import numpy as np

a = radians(10)
b = radians(15)
g = radians(67)

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_rotations
rx = np.array([
    [cos(g), -sin(g), 0],
    [sin(g), cos(g), 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
])
ry = np.array([
    [cos(b), 0, sin(b)],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [-sin(b), 0, cos(b)],
])
rz = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, cos(a), -sin(a)],
    [0, sin(a), cos(a)],
])
r = rz @ ry @ rx
print("rotation matrix")
print(r)

# rotated basis vectors
x = r.T[0]
y = r.T[1]
z = r.T[2]

print("magnitudes")
print(np.linalg.norm(x))
print(np.linalg.norm(y))
print(np.linalg.norm(z))

print("dots")
print(np.dot(x, y))
print(np.dot(y, z))
print(np.dot(x, z))
```

rotation does not change the shape so every basis vector must be perpendicular. (AFAIK)

however, output of this script shows that the dot products of the basis vectors are not zero.

this is the output of my script

```
rotation matrix
[[ 0.37741729 -0.88913941  0.25881905]
 [ 0.92408112  0.34342438 -0.16773126]
 [ 0.0602517   0.30247447  0.95125124]]
magnitudes
1.0
1.0
0.9999999999999999
dots
-2.7755575615628914e-17
0.0
1.3877787807814457e-17
```

why does this produce non-zero dot product?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> In two words, round-off error.

Comment: Round-off error, one assumes. Those numbers are on the order of $10^{-17}$.

Comment: These are $-2^{-55},\,0,\,2^{-56}$, which makes sense if you understand how Python's floating-point arithmetic works.

Comment: @stackcrumple See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/2476977).

Comment: Thank you all!Dealing with round-off error seems very hard...